# Skip buggy Inputs and loop over

Tags: python, loops, indico

I have a huge file with tweets, unfortunately a few of tweets are in unsupported format for sentiment api. I want to skip over such tweets and continue to upload rest and get a response back. I think I am stuck in a infinite loop. help me!

how will i know if the tweet is buggy?, as far as my knowledge goes no response is an indicator for it, so is this line correct

```
if (indicoio.emotion(row))=='FALSE':
```

---

```
import indicoio
import csv
import json
import itertools

indicoio.config.api_key = 'key'

json_file = open("xaa31.json", "w")
x=1
with open('output3.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    so = csv.reader(csvfile)
    while x < 12001:
        for (row=[x]) in so:
            if (indicoio.emotion(row))=='FALSE':
                print x
                x+=1
            else:
#        print (indicoio.emotion(row))
                jsonout=indicoio.emotion(row)
                json.dump(jsonout, json_file, indent=2)
                json_file.write(",\n")
                x+=1

json_file.close()
print 'done'
```